# Android Jetpack CameraX method createSurfaceProvider() not found

Tags: java, android, camera

I ran into a problem when working with CameraX on the tutorial from the android documentation. I can't find a method `createSurfaceProvider()`

I am using these libraries: `camerax_version = "1.0.0-beta10"`

**CODE**:

```
@Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        previewView = view.findViewById(R.id.previewView);

        ListenableFuture<ProcessCameraProvider> cameraProviderFuture =
                ProcessCameraProvider.getInstance(requireContext());

        cameraProviderFuture.addListener(() -> {
            try {
                ProcessCameraProvider cameraProvider = cameraProviderFuture.get();
                bindPreview(cameraProvider);

            } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {

            }
        }, ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(requireContext()));
    }

    private void bindPreview(ProcessCameraProvider cameraProvider) {
        Preview preview = new Preview.Builder().build();

        imageCapture = new ImageCapture.Builder()
                .setCaptureMode(ImageCapture.CAPTURE_MODE_MINIMIZE_LATENCY)
                .build();

        CameraSelector cameraSelector = new CameraSelector.Builder()
                .requireLensFacing(CameraSelector.LENS_FACING_BACK)
                .build();

        Camera camera = cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(
                ((LifecycleOwner) this),
                cameraSelector,
                preview,
                imageCapture);

        preview.setSurfaceProvider(
                previewView.createSurfaceProvider(camera.getCameraInfo()));
            
                            ↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑
    }
```

Comment: it was changed to `getSurfaceProvider`, and you can call it like `.surfaceProvider` in Kotlin. For example, `somePreviewView.surfaceProvider`.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Just followed the latest [tutorial](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/camerax-getting-started/#0) and faced with same issue.
But if you simply call the property surfaceProvider of your preview everything will work.

> val preview = Preview.Builder()
> .build()
> .also {
> it.setSurfaceProvider(viewFinder.surfaceProvider)
> }

Answer (score 8):

Just replace

```
preview.setSurfaceProvider(previewView.createSurfaceProvider(camera.getCameraInfo()));
```

with

```
preview.setSurfaceProvider(previewView.getSurfaceProvider());
```

Answer (score 0):

preview.setSurfaceProvider(mBinding.cameraPreviewView.getSurfaceProvider());

Answer (score -2):

Change the gradle dependency to this :
implementation "androidx.camera:camera-camera2:1.0.0-rc01"
It should work